# R xml2 extract element from xbrl file

Tags: r, xml, xbrl, xml2

Can someone please help me understand why I am unable to extract a node / element from this xml file?  Technically it is an xbrl file, but I would expect the R xml2 library to work just the same.

Read in the file. The 3rd element or node appears to be unit. This code works as expected:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)


eqr <- read_xml(x = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/906107/000156459018010687/eqr-20180331.xml")

View(eqr)

xml_child(eqr, 3)
```

However, I can't get this code to work:

```
xml_find_first(eqr, xpath = "unit")
```

Searching for other elements with this method works as expected:

```
xml_find_first(eqr, xpath = "us-gaap:OperatingLeasesIncomeStatementLeaseRevenue")
xml_find_first(eqr, xpath = "us-gaap:OperatingLeasesIncomeStatementLeaseRevenue") %>%
 xml_double()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very typical issue when dealing with XML files as document has a default namespace denoted with no colon-separated prefix: `xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"`.

As a result, nodes not in a local namespace is bound to this default and any XPath should run a user-defined prefix to map node to it. Fortunately, `xml2` allows this as `xml_find_first` maintains a third argument, *ns*, that takes a named vector or `xml_ns()` call:

```
# CREATED DOC PREFIX AND INCLUDED IN XPATH
xml_find_first(eqr, xpath = "doc:unit", ns = c(doc="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"))

# {xml_node}
# <unit id="U_shares">
# [1] <measure>shares</measure>
```

Alternatively, `xml2` also allows default namespaces to be stripped:

```
xml_find_first(xml_ns_strip(eqr), xpath = "unit")

# {xml_node}
# <unit id="U_shares">
# [1] <measure>shares</measure>
```

Comment: Both pieces of code work. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Voting up the answer; I just wanted to add that I recommend using `xbrli` as the prefix bound to the `http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance` namespace. While, in XML, prefixes do not matter in theory, the XBRL community has established a practice to be globally consistent in the way prefixes are used, especially for standard namespaces (see for example https://xbrl.us/xbrl-reference/standard-units/ ). Sticking to these prefixes will make the code easier to understand for XBRL specialists. Some specifications (OIM) and authorities even enforce some prefixes officially.